# How to kill properly all processes launched by the application?

Tags: python, kill-process

We have a big application written in Python. We wish to cleanly kill processes that have been launched by our application when we close or interrupt it.  However, through Python code (e.g.  subprocess.Popen or os.system), we have a command *A* which launches another subcommand *B* but the command *B* seems to have no relation with the command *A*. The father process of the command *B* is the init process (with pid 1). How to kill the process *B* in Python code (e.g. after Ctrl+C)?

For example, we have 2 shell scripts and one Python script which calls these shell scripts.

the first Shell script *mycommand1.sh* is:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 3600 &
```

the second Shell script *mycommand2.sh* is:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 3600
```

the Python script *myscript.py* is:

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

def launchCommands():

    proc1 = subprocess.Popen('./mycommand1.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    print "the processus 1 has started"

    proc2 = subprocess.Popen('./mycommand2.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    print "the processus 2 has started"

    return proc1, proc2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc1 = None
    proc2 = None
    try:
        proc1, proc2 = launchCommands()
        while True:
            pass

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Ctrl+C received! ..."

        print "trying to kill the processus 2"
        os.killpg(os.getpgid(proc2.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
        print "processus 2 has been killed"

        print "trying to kill the processus 1"
        os.killpg(os.getpgid(proc1.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
        print "processus 1 has been killed"
```

Then we execute our Python script and we interrupt it after 3 seconds with a Ctrl+C.
Here is the output after the interruption.

```
$> python myscript.py
the processus 1 has started
the processus 2 has started
^CCtrl+C received! ...
trying to kill the processus 2
processus 2 has been killed
trying to kill the processus 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myscript.py", line 33, in <module>
  os.killpg(os.getpgid(proc1.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
```

We display all "sleep" processes while and after the execution of the Python script (Of course, there is no sleep process before the execution of the Python script).

While running the myscript.py command:

```
$> ps -ef | grep sleep
  501 50700     1   0  2:21   ??         0:00.00 sleep 3600
  501 50701 50699   0  2:21   ??         0:00.00 sleep 3600
  501 50703   410   0  2:21   ttys002    0:00.00 grep sleep
```

After interrupting the program with Ctrl + C:

```
$> ps -ef | grep sleep
  501 50700     1   0  2:21   ??         0:00.00 sleep 3600
  501 51025   410   0  2:23   ttys002    0:00.00 grep sleep
```

As we can see, the process 1 we try to kill does not exist anymore and one process sleep whose the father pid is 1 always exists. This process sleep comes from the execution of the script mycommand1.sh. How to kill properly this process sleep in the script myscript.py (of course, we do not wish to kill all sleep process)?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I made everything that you described

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest to my problem. I made these experiments on a Mac (macOS Sierra 10.12.3) and my version of Python is 2.7.13. I have copied all codes I have written in my question, I have just added rights  for the shell scripts before to launch the python command (chmod 755 mycommand*.sh) and I have well reproduced the problem.

Comment: I test it on Ubuntu 17, and can't reproduce it. I tested it on Python 2.7.13 as well.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in platform?

Comment: Can you paste `print(os.getpgid(proc1or2.pid))` before every `os.kill` ?

Comment: Maybe. I put your command line before `os.kill` and I have an error message for the proc 1. Then, I have added your command line in the infinite loop (with replacing the line pass), and it prints a lot of times the ppid of the 2 scripts and then it crashes (I did not make Ctrl+c). I think it crashes when the command mycommand1.sh has been finished to execute. Maybe, on Linux, the command mycommand1.sh does not finish before the end of `sleep 3600 &`?

Comment: the error message is _OSError: [Errno 3] No such process_

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite `mycommand1.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
foo(){
    cnt=0
    while [ $cnt -le 100 ]; do
        cnt=$((cnt+1))
        echo $0 $cnt
        sleep 1
    done
}

foo &
```

and `mycommand2.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
foo(){
    cnt=0
    while [ $cnt -le 100 ]; do
        cnt=$((cnt+1))
        echo $0 $cnt
        sleep 1
    done
}

foo
```

Remove `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` from `myscript.py`
And check it.